# How to access Jupyter Notebook via http (instead of https)?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I think this was working in the past, however, with a later version of jupyter notebook, it seems to allow only https connection. Is there any way I could still get http working?

Comment: It allows both. Maybe you have some configs files in the hidden `.jupyter` folder in your HOME folder that enforce the https. Pls read the [documentation](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public_server.html#notebook-public-server)

Comment: @gdlmx Thanks. Could you elaborate more on where the setting for http/https is?

Comment: A list of common options can be found [here](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html#config-file-and-command-line-options). The related options are `NotebookApp.certfile` and `.keyfile`